# Transforming and Combining Random Variables Clarification

Tags: statistics, random-variables

My textbook has again been very ambiguous about this subject, coud someone verify if my reasoning is correct:

A swimmer enters a 100m event in which he will win a prize if his total time is under 4 minutes. He may choose to calculate his total time in three ways:

A: He swims 100m once, multiplying his time by 4 to get his total time.

B: He swims 100m four times, and adds his four times together to get his total time. Assume that the four swims are independent and identically distributed.

C: He chooses both A and B (swimming 100m five times), and his total time is the average of his total time for choice A and his total time for choice B. Assume the five swim times are independent and identically distributed.

*With which choice, A or B, is the expected value of total time larger?*

I would assume that the expected times are equal, as $E[4*X] = 4*E[X]$.

*With which choice, A or B, is the variance of total time larger?*

I would assume that $A$ would have a larger variance, as $\sigma^2*constant^2>\sigma^2*4$.

*Suppose he chooses option C, and his 100m swim time (in seconds) is normally distributed with mean 61 and variance 5. What is the variance of his total time?*

I would expect the variance to be $25$, as $((5*4^2)+(5*4))*(0.5^2)=25$, as $Var[X+Y]=Var[X]+Var[Y]$, and variation is multiplied by the square of the constant.

Thanks!

Comment: Your calculations are correct. When we multiply by $4$, you might as well be explicit and say that the variance is $16\sigma^2$.  Except in the very implausible variance $0$ possibility, this is greater than $4\sigma^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally correct, if a bit imprecisely stated in parts.

First, define the random variables of interest precisely.  Let $X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5$ be five swimming times for 100 meters each, and these are all assumed to be independent and identically distributed.

Then $A = 4X_1$, and define $B = X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5$, and $C = (A+B)/2 = X_1 + (X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5)/4$.  If $\operatorname{E}[X_i] = \mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}[X_i] = \sigma^2$ for each $i = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5$, then we clearly have $$\operatorname{E}[A] = \operatorname{E}[4X_1] = 4\operatorname{E}[X_1] = 4\mu,$$ and $$\operatorname{E}[B] = \operatorname{E}[X_2 + X_3 + X_4 + X_5] = \operatorname{E}[X_2] + \operatorname{E}[X_3] + \operatorname{E}[X_4] + \operatorname{E}[X_5] = 4\mu,$$ so the expectations of both $A$ and $B$ are equal.  Note this result does not depend on the independence of the individual swimming times:  all that is required is that each swimming time has the same mean $\mu$.  The above follows only from the linearity of expectation.

However, calculating the variance (of $B$) does require the assumption of independence:  $$\operatorname{Var}[A] = \operatorname{Var}[4X_1] = 16\operatorname{Var}[X_1] = 16\sigma^2,$$ but $$\operatorname{Var}[B] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[X_2] + \operatorname{Var}[X_3] + \operatorname{Var}[X_4] + \operatorname{Var}[X_5] = 4\sigma^2,$$ thus the variance in the total swimming time for $A$ is strictly greater than that for $B$.

The last part of the question asks for $\operatorname{Var}[C]$ where each $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu = 61, \sigma^2 = 5).$$  We find $$\operatorname{Var}[C] = \operatorname{Var}[(A+B)/2] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \frac{1}{4}(\operatorname{Var}[A] + \operatorname{Var}[B]) = \frac{1}{4}(16\sigma^2 + 4\sigma^2) = 5\sigma^2 = 25.$$